# DotNetOpenAuth vs ServiceStack Authentication

Tags: servicestack, dotnetopenauth

I'm quite new to ServiceStack so please forgive my ignorance if I ask any questions that appear obvious.

I've got a site that is already authenticating users using dotnetopenauth using the normal examples available online. Got a login button which posts to this method:

```
Public Sub ExecuteGoogleLogin()
    Dim Url As String = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"
    Dim OpenID As New OpenIdRelyingParty
    Dim HostedMeta As New HostMetaDiscoveryService() With {.UseGoogleHostedHostMeta = True}
    Dim ReturnUrl As String = Request.Url.ToString

    OpenID.DiscoveryServices.Insert(0, HostedMeta)

    Dim builder As New UriBuilder(ReturnUrl)
    Dim fetch As New FetchRequest()


    Dim Req = OpenID.CreateRequest(Url, Realm.AutoDetect, builder.Uri)

    fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email)
    fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First)
    fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last)

    Req.AddExtension(fetch)

    Req.RedirectToProvider()
End Sub
```

Which will then redirect back to the page that will check for the response, like

```
  Private Sub CheckOpenIDResponse()
    Dim Rp As New OpenIdRelyingParty
    Dim Resp = Rp.GetResponse()
    Dim Subsc As Subscriber

Select Case Resp.Status
            Case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated
                Dim Fetch = Resp.GetExtension(Of FetchResponse)()

                Email = Fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email)
....
```

Prettly standard and works fine (only supports google for now) but it works. I've got my AppHost working, got some test Dto's working as expected now just need to implement Authentication. So my questions are:

1. How can I convert this barebones code to work using servicestack's authentication classes (GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider etc)? and get rid of dotnetopenauth completely.  or...
2. In ServiceStack, find a way to use dotnetopenauth (or the code above) to implement the authentication.

Maybe there is something obvious I'm missing in the SS documentation, but for the life of me I can't seem figure out how to put it all together.

To get the session from the calling page, I wrapped my user object (Known as Subscriber), in a CustomUserSession.

```
    Dim Ahost = ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.EndpointHost.AppHost
    Dim Key = ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.SessionFeature.GetSessionKey()
    Dim Sess As CustomUserSession = Ahost.TryResolve(Of ServiceStack.CacheAccess.ICacheClient)().[Get](Of CustomUserSession)(Key)
```

Then from here I use the session as I wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how the code above would integrate with ServiceStack. Slightly biased but I would let ServiceStack handle this using `GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider`. Also, the [SocialBootstrapApi](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi) project should make a good reference.

The setup/configureation below gives you the url `'{servicestack path}/auth/googleopenid` which would handle the authentication.

Assuming you have ServiceStack installed...

**Nuget Install (or just referenece the ServiceStack.Authention.OpenId.dll)**  If you do the Nuget Install it should modify your Web.Config with most of the configuration below (think you don't get appSettings configuration)

**In AppHost add AuthFeature Plugin with GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider**

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] { new GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider(new AppSettings())}));     
}
```

**Add some specific urls for GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider**

```
<appSettings>
<add key="oauth.GoogleOpenId.RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost" />
<add key="oauth.GoogleOpenId.CallbackUrl" value="http://localhost/api/auth/GoogleOpenId" /> 
</appSettings>
```

**Bunch of configuration within Web.config. Should be added with NuGet install of ServiceStack.Authentication.OpenId**

```
<configsections>
    <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth">
      <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>


  <dotNetOpenAuth>
    <!-- This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized. -->
    <!-- For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/ -->
    <openid>
      <relyingParty>
        <security requireSsl="false">
          <!-- Uncomment the trustedProviders tag if your relying party should only accept positive assertions from a closed set of OpenID Providers. -->
          <!--<trustedProviders rejectAssertionsFromUntrustedProviders="true">
                        <add endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud" />
                    </trustedProviders>-->
        </security>
        <behaviors>
          <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                         with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
          <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth" />
        </behaviors>
      </relyingParty>
    </openid>
    <messaging>
      <untrustedWebRequest>
        <whitelistHosts>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
          <!--<add name="localhost" />-->
        </whitelistHosts>
      </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>
    <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
    <reporting enabled="true" />
  </dotNetOpenAuth>
```

**Access AuthUserSession data**

In your ServiceStack service (class that inherits from Service) you can use:

```
var sess = this.GetSession();
```

Outside of ServiceStack you can do something like:

```
var key = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey();
var sess = appHost.TryResolve<ICacheClient>().Get<AuthUserSession>(key);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Installed the OpenID libs and changed the web.config urls for localhost to match my dev setup. I've added the Authenticate Attribute and it seems as though it's trying to redirect to google but failing. 

It errors out with 'handler for request not found' obviously cause the url is localhost/myapp/svc/login?redirect=http://localhost..

Comment: Strangely enough if I navigate straight to the url localhost/myapp/svc/auth/GoogleOpenId it successfully redirects to google.

Comment: Hmmm - Do you have a Service or Route to handle GET requests to path '/login'.

Comment: Nope, got no routes to handle /login. Been assuming this all in-built in ServiceStack's openid libs based off settings from web.config? i.e. CallbackUrl, RedirectUrl etc?

Comment: Wow, finally got the url working. Now I'm getting a new error, this one seems particular to my case. Once google authenticates, it redrects back and throw a CultureNotFoundException, apparently ServiceStack doesn't recogonise my country.

Culture is not supported. Parameter name: name en-KE is an invalid culture identifier.

Some googling suggests that I should just try{}catch this and ignore it. Final question, how do I then access the user's details from the  auth provider once it's successful? I'm using asp.net webforms.

Comment: Updated answer with a few ways to get user's details

Comment: Seems I underestimated the CultureNotFound exception, the code doesn't even get to the OnAuthenticated method of the UserSession, just bugs out somewhere before.


<pre>
 [REQUEST: {provider:googleopenid}]System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported. Parameter name: name en-KE is an invalid culture identifier. at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String name) at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.SimpleRegistration.ClaimsResponse.get_Culture() at ServiceStack.Authentication.OpenId.OpenIdExtensions.ToDictionary(ClaimsResponse response) ....</pre>

Comment: Taken a while but I finally managed to sort out the CultureInfo bug and managed to get a CustomUserSession up and running. I know how to get the session from with the AppHost, now how do I get it from my Master page?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out from the wiki. Answer appended to question.